# Terraform Azure Key Vault - context deadline exceeded

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to provision a simple `keyvault` in `azure` using `terraform` and I get the following error:

> Error: retrieving `contact` for KeyVault: keyvault.BaseClient#GetCertificateContacts: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded

And here's my terraform snippet:

```
# data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "aks_key_vault" {
  name                        = var.aks_kv_name
  location                    = var.location
  resource_group_name         = var.rg_name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
#   soft_delete_retention_days  = var.aks_kv_soft_delete_retention_days
#   purge_protection_enabled    = false

  sku_name = var.aks_kv_sku

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azuread_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions     = var.aks_kv_key_permissions
    secret_permissions  = var.aks_kv_secret_permissions
    storage_permissions = var.aks_kv_storage_permissions
  }
  tags = merge(var.common_tags)
}
```

and here's the `variables.tf`

```
# Key Vault related variables
aks_kv_name                       = "jana-azure-csi-kv"
aks_kv_soft_delete_retention_days = 7
aks_kv_sku                        = "standard"
aks_kv_key_permissions            = ["Get"]
aks_kv_secret_permissions         = ["Get"]
aks_kv_storage_permissions        = ["Get"]
```

Can someone help me understand what is the issue and how to fix it?

`terraform` version:

```
Terraform v1.3.6
on darwin_amd64
```

`azurerm` version:

```
version = "=3.0.0"
```

Comment: Could you please mention which version of Terraform and azurerm are being consumed here?

Comment: Hi @SwarnaAnipindi I updated my question. Could you check now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**'context deadline exceeded'** means the respected action won't be done with in timeframe.  **Mostly it was caused because of network connection issue.**

Here the issue was caused because of terraform version, as part of solution please upgrade or keep > on provider
**From:  version = "3.0.0" To version = ">=3.0.0"**

after that please run below command

```
terraform init -upgrade
```

[image]

Replicate the same issue via below code. Here is the code snippet used to create [keyvault](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault)

**Main tf file as follows:**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "**********"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    key_vault {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy    = true
      recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults = true
    }
  }
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "swarnademokeyvault"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]
  }
}
```

**Provider tf file as follows:**

terraform {

```
  required_version = "~>1.3.3"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
       source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
       version = ">=3.0.0"
         }
       }
```

}

**When we ran below command**

```
terraform plan
```

[image]

**While run apply**

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

**Verification:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all your support. I will check and get back to you. Could you help me with my other question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784064/terraform-azure-kubernetes-nodepool-recreates-every-time-when-apply-terraform`

Comment: Thank You.  Could you please mention which version of Terraform and azurerm are being consumed here?  Is it the same version there as well?

Comment: it is the `version = ">=3.0.0"`

Comment: Just a note the 3.0.0 is not the 'Terraform version' (which is v1.3.6) it is instead the azurerm provider version.

Also, how did you determine that the problem was the provider version?

I've got a similar issue
`Error: updating Access Policy for Vault keyvault.VaultsClient#UpdateAccessPolicy: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded`
I'm using tf v=1.3.5 and azurerm v=3.52.0. 
This is a new issue so with our versions being fixed and working before, I don't see why it would be the provider or tf version being the issue?

Comment: I forgot to mention, my error comes up after 30mins of waiting for the policy update 
`module.kv_main.module.azdev_group_access_policy.azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.keyvault_policy: Still creating... [29m50s elapsed]`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while deploying Terraform on an Azure Key Vault, which caused my `terraform plan` step to halt, even after the advice in the accepted answer was implemented. The error message was cryptic:

```bash
Error: retrieving `contact` for KeyVault: 
keyvault.BaseClient#GetCertificateContacts: 
Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context canceled
```

I can see a number of [similar issues reported on GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/17863), which didn't solve the issue I was having.

However, I found a comprehensive explanation of this issue and a solution in this [blog post](https://www.ericksegaar.com/2022/11/29/key-vault-contacts-and-rbac-roles-in-terraform/).

The problem stems from setting certificate contacts, which are used for email notifications when certificates expire. To set these contacts, you need the "manage contacts" access policy. [The official Azure Key Vault Terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault) tries to check on the status of the contact configuration. This makes sense.

But, if you don't plan to use certificates for this Key Vault (for secrets only), this error can be frustrating and cryptic. This can also be troublesome if you intend to leverage RBAC for Key Vault access, a recommendation made in the Azure Portal as of now, as the Terraform module currently only supports this configuration via access policies.

I solved my issue by enabling RBAC for access control by adding the following to the Terraform configuration and switching the lifecycle checks off for contacts.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "aks_key_vault" {
  # ...other configurations...

  enable_rbac_authorization = true

  # Disable certificate lifecycle contact checks
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [contact]
  }

  network_acls {
    bypass = "AzureServices"
    # I have no VPN/subnets configured for the moment, so we'll allow external traffic.
    default_action = "Allow"
    # If you did have subnets, configure them here and make sure the agents running your
    # Terraform operations have access to these subnets.
    # virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.v-subnet.id]
  }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `access_policy` property when enabling RBAC, since you must use either access policies **OR** RBAC access control methods for an Azure  Key Vault.

Assuming you did want to manage certificates, one thing that is not so obvious from that blog post is the Azure RBAC you need to perform. If you Google the role definition that is used, you'll find that any service principle or user performing Terraform operations will need to have a role assignment for the `Key Vault Certificates Officer` role at this scope.

After making these changes, I was able to run my Terraform plan without issues.

For those who still want to perform certificate lifecycle checks, the blog post provides an Azure CLI-dependent workaround that works like so:

```
resource "null_resource" "add_contacts" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    // add az cli command to add certificate contact to keyvault when it does not exists already
    command = "az keyvault certificate contact list --vault-name ${var.keyvault_name} | jq -r '.[].emailAddress' | grep -q ${var.support_email} || az keyvault certificate contact add --vault-name ${var.keyvault_name} --email ${var.support_email} --name ${var.support_name}"
    when    = create
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.rbac_role
  ]
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I am having the same issue but this was working all along and started all of a sudden. Any idea why?

Comment: Also its working when I am running from my local machine but failed from build server

Comment: Regarding the issue you're encountering, here are a couple of potential solutions:

**1)** Confirm if you've executed `az login` on localhost. If yes, it's possible that the credentials used in your deployment pipeline have expired or lack the necessary Azure RBAC permissions. Ensure the credentials have roles like `Key Vault Certificates Officer` to interact with the key vault effectively.

**2)** Check for any recent alterations in your network configuration. e.g. If your office location was whitelisted for access and your CI/CD server wasn't, it might explain the connectivity issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I figured out the issue is with only Plan command. Whenever I run a plan command if the KV has Private Endpoint plan fails(apply works).